# In a binomial population Check if $\bar{p}=\frac{x}{n}$ is a consistent estimator of $p$.

Tags: probability

In a binomial population Check if $\bar{p}=\frac{x}{n}$ is a consistent estimator of $p$.

**My attempt**
If we prove 
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}E(\frac{x}{n})-p=0$$

and

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}V(\frac{x}{n})=0$$ then the  estimator is consistent.

We know $E(\frac{x}{n})=\frac{1}{n}E(x)=\frac{1\times n\times p}{n}=p$ then 
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}E(\frac{x}{n})-p=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}p-p=0$$

For $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}V(\frac{x}{n})=0$$

I'm stuck can someone help me?

Comment: "Poblation"????

Comment: sorry, bad english @DavidG.Stork

Comment: Please fix the body of your question as well.

Answer (score 1):

$$V(\frac{x}{n}) = \frac{1}{n^2} V(x).$$
Now use what you know about the variance of a binomial random variable...

Comment: I don't see very clear why $V(\frac{x}{n}) = \frac{1}{n^2} V(x).$ can you explain that please? thanks for your answer

Comment: @Bvss12 In general, if $X$ is a random variable and $c$ is a constant, then $V(cX) = c^2 V(X)$. You can prove this directly from the definition of variance.